# getElementById with changing IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I need to hide all the elements that have the string **"replies-36965584"** anywhere in their IDs.

HTML:

```
<div id="replies-36965584_1">aaaa</div>
<div id="replies-36965584_2">aaaa</div>
<div id="replies-36965584_3">aaaa</div>
<div id="replies-36965584_4">aaaa</div>
<div id="replies-36222224_2">nnnn</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("replies-36965584").style.display="none"
```

How can I modify this JS to select the first four elements?

Comment: ?? How about calling `getElementById` etc once for each different value? Or give the elements a special class and find & hide them that way?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why don't you use `name=".."` and `getElementsByName(..)`.

Comment: How are you hiding them? Bodyload? Click?

Comment: >calling getElementById etc once for each it's impossible, as new elements are generated daily. >Or give the elements a special class and find & hide them that way? Class has already been given. 
>How are you hiding them? Bodyload? Click?
They're hidden nn bodylaod.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS and attribute selectors.

> #### [att^=val]
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

---

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6B6S/)

#### CSS

```
[id^="replies-36965584_"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using jQuery an option? If so, this is dead simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^="replies-36965584"]').hide();
});
```

If you're unfamiliar with jQuery, here's a link to get started: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/

**EDIT**: Fixed syntax error.

**EDIT**: Added jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbVp9/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know certain literal values but you know the general pattern and only the number will change, then I will consider some matching with regular expresiion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the painful way:

```
var o = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0;i<o.length;i++) { 
    if(o[i].id.indexOf('replies-36965584') == 0) {
        o[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with vanilla javascript that I know of, is to fetch all the divs on the page, and test the id's for the ones you want.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    var div = divs[i];
    if (/replies-36965584/.test(div.id)) {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```